# QinQ and selective QinQ

Tags: vlan, trunk, qinq

What is difference between QinQ  and selective QinQ ?

We need to configure selective QinQ  VLAN trunk between our setup.

Please help in selective QinQ .

Comment: Removed the off-topic request for a product/resource recommendation.

Comment: You will need to provide your device models and configurations for help with configuration.

Comment: We are going to use Brocade MLX/CER device for selective Q-in-Q.can we acheive selective q-in-q using these models?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

QinQ is a method to tag already tagged frames with an outer frame. It is like a layer-2 tunneling on a trunk. Selective QinQ allows you to tag some of the tagged frames, but not others.